# XCTestManifests in generated swift package

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I am currently creating a Swift Package. By default, the package generated by Xcode contains the XCTestManifests file with the following code:

```
#if !canImport(ObjectiveC)
public func allTests() -> [XCTestCaseEntry] {
    return [
        testCase(TestPkgTests.allTests),
    ]
}
#endif
```

As you can see, this is the function that returns all test cases. However, I am curious when it will be called and in what case the condition `!CanImport (ObjectiveC)` will be satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is needed for running tests on platforms other than macOS.

On macOS the test runner relies on the ObjectiveC runtime which is absent on other platforms, hence `canImport(ObjectiveC)` is `false`. The `allTests()` function is called from `LinuxMain.swift` file, you can generate it on macOS by running `swift test --generate-linuxmain`.

In newer SwiftPM releases there is an alternative option for running tests on those platforms: `swift test --enable-test-discovery`. You can read more about it here: https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-enable-test-discovery-by-default/36619

Comment: When you "say platforms other than macOS", does this also include iOS? tvOS? iPadOS? watchOS?

Comment: @scaly yeap, it applies to other target platforms made by Apple as well. I meant that the host platform is macOS, while the target platform might be iOS/watchOS/etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.4: Automatic Test Discovery Included**

[Swift 5.4 (April 26, 2021 release)](https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-5-4-released/) includes test discovery by default.

> Automatic test discovery is now the default on all platforms

`swift test --enable-test-discovery` is no longer needed.

The Swift 5.4+ `swift package init` template does not generate `allTests` and `XCTestManifests.swift`.